# Interaction between a React component and a web page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Assume I have a shiny new React component for rendering markdown and ye old legacy static HTML form, where user types text into `textarea`

Now I want to enhance this form a little: I want to display my React component alongside and render markdown as user types.

So, basically, I need to set component's props from HTML.

Next thing

Assume I have a React component that displays set of pics and lets user to click and mark one as active. It draws a fancy blue border around the active image and everyone are happy.

Now I have ye old HTML form and I want to send selected picture's id to my server.

So, basically, I need to read component's props (or state) and put it in the hidden field of the form

How do I achieve this? I also might have multiple separate components on my page

Comment: You would use `ReactDOM.render()` to pass properties and callbacks. Can you show an example?

Comment: And as for your 2nd question: give your react image components an onFocus handler, and in that handler, put the id prop of the image in the hidden field of the form.